# application.js not loading on rails app; Failed to clear tmp storage. Security Error ; Chrome

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I have a rails app (on the dev server) and the `application.js` file is not loaded from the browser. When I make a direct call to the `application.js` file from the browser ex: `myapp.com/assets/application.js-fingerprint` it loads the javascript.

I have done the following and I suspect I may have done certain things incorrectly.

1. I deployed the app on the dev server
2. Ran `RAILS_ENV='dev' bundle exec rake assets:clean`
3. After that `RAILS_ENV='dev' bundle exec rake assets:clobber`
4. Finally `RAILS_ENV='dev' bundle exec rake assets:precompile`
5. `touch tmp/restart.txt` (to restart passenger)
6. `sudo service httpd restart` (while I know it's redundant to restart apache, I still went ahead and did so)

I use Apache, Rails 4.0, Capistrano 2.X.

I would really appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Update:

1. It's an AWS instance running Amazon linux (flavour of CentOS)
2. I get the following message on the javascript console on chrome developer tools.

> Failed to clear temp storage: It was determined that certain files
>   are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls
>   are being made on file resources. SecurityError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i usually run  rake assets:precompile and service apache2 reload on root of my app on my server. try service apache2 reload

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried running it. apache2 is not recognised on my machine as it's CentOS.

Comment: sudo service httpd reload should work for you , but idk wath is happening on your server , wath u did should work :/ i didn't want to post an answer but a comment ... but can't cause of my reputation ...

Comment: Update: I get this error on the javascript console using chrome developer tools: 
`Failed to clear temp storage: It was determined that certain files are unsafe for access within a Web application, or that too many calls are being made on file resources. SecurityError`

Comment: Marking this as resolved. Thanks for the help Tanguy